# In Star Wars: The Clone Wars are clones allowed to be in romantic relationships?

Tags: star-wars, the-clone-wars

I understand that they're soldiers for life. But I don't recall them taking an oath that bans this type of relationship. We were shown that they do have free time when Fives visits the clone bar.

Comment: if i made a clone army would grow them without parts/castrate them. though i have no proof on the matter, just seems fairly logical, alot of armies in earth history did the same. eunuchs ftw.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with Clone Wars canon, so don't know if they were even allowed the free time to have an OPTION of having a romantic relationship. BUT, in the after-Endor EU, there were examples of clones (Baron Fel's clones, specifically) that "settled down" and started families. Presumably it was allowed as they were a sleeper cell and had to have families for camouflage.

Comment: Do you mean clones dating other clones? or do you mean romantic relationships outside of the clones?

Comment: The only mention of a regular (i.e. not Boba Fett) clone trooper being married is [Cut Lawquane](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Cut_Lawquane), who was a special case as he deserted (which makes you wonder about the loyalty programming/breeding).

Comment: The answer is no they were not allowed to form relationships though they were allowed to visit the twi'lek courtesans.  At least according to the novels.

Comment: @Chad - From the Republic Commando novels, the clone commando Darman had a romantic relationship with someone, and those over him did know about it (though the fact he was a commando probably gave him more flexibility)

Comment: @SSumner - Maybe I should have qualified that the standing orders for the 501st were no relationships were permitted outside of the unit.  That is romantic or otherwise.  Clearly there were clones other than in the 501st

Comment: IIRC, there were a few females hanging around the clone bar on Coruscant, and at least one could be heard flirting.

Comment: There's a lot going on between scenes that goes unsaid.

Answer (score 2):

In the show, there is no evidence of clones having a romantic relationship besides Cut Lawquane, but he did desert, so that negates him as an example. While there are no instances where a clone is reprimanded for having one, that does not mean that clones don't have romantic relationships.

But, due to the lack of examples or reference at all in the show, we can only assume that clones would not be allowed to have romantic relationships. This could be because of the same reasons that soldiers in our world cannot: they could be persuaded to give out information to a spy on accident or it would distract the soldiers from their duty.

Comment: But soldiers in our world *can* and do have romantic relationships.  In most militaries it's highly encouraged for soldiers to have lives outside their expected duties as this can and does benefit the militaries as a whole.

Comment: @monty I think that the rules and expectation different in most of Asia than in the west.

Comment: But isn't the LACK of these relationships that cause problems?  Of course you can kidnap these people, but I assume it would be far more complicated than giving you a random hooker...

Comment: Most Soldier's across the world are allowed to have relationships. I was a Soldier, so was my wife, we aren't robots. There is however a rule against having sex in a combat zone, like Afghanistan, mostly to avoid STDs and unwanted pregnancy. As you can imagine, this rule is violated often. There were not many relationships for clone troopers due to lack of time and opportunity.

Answer (score 0):

Clone troopers were not programmed against relationships or were altered against physical relationships because the Kaminoans found that those that were made poorer troopers. However, most clones had a very limited chance to actually pursue any kind of relationship due to the demands of the war and the fact that clones weren't initially allowed leave, pay or much rest. Some Jedi commanders did go out of their way to give the clones more freedom and down time, and eventually petitioned for more equal treatment for their clone troops.

"Clone troopers were not paid at all and did not originally have leave privileges. There is no known regulation against marriage, but standard troops had such limited interaction with individuals outside of the army that romantic relationships were a rarity."

I hope this helps! Link to the star wars wiki below.

http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Cloning/Legends

Answer (score 0):

### Possibly.

79's, the clone bar that you mentioned, was frequented by quite a few female non-clones.

At least one female patron seemed to be on the prowl, commenting this upon seeing Rako Hardeen.

> Wow, I want to check his midi-chlorian count.

Answer (score -2):

Actually, in the episode with Cut, he said they were programmed not to have any relationship. I think.

Comment: Do you have a clip or maybe the dialog to backup your answer?

Comment: his name is "I'm not lying" isn't that proof enough?